# dataframes selecting data by [] and by .(attibute)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found out that I have problem understanding when I should be accessing data from dataframe(df) using `df[data]` or `df.data` . 
I mostly use the [] method to create new columns, but I can also access data using both `df[]` and `df.data`, but what's the difference and how can I better grasp those two ways of selecting data? When one should be used over the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/indexing.html#attribute-access) correctly, they are pretty much equivalent, except in these cases:

> - You can use [the `.`] access only if the index element is a valid python identifier, e.g. s.1 is not allowed.
> - The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. s.min is not allowed.
> - Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: index, major_axis, minor_axis, items, labels.
> - In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. s['1'], s['min'], and s['index'] will access the corresponding element or column.

However, while

> indexing operators `[]` and attribute operator `.` provide quick and easy
>   access to pandas data structures across a wide range of use cases [...]

in production you should really use the optimized panda data access methods such as `.loc`, `.iloc`, and `.ix`, because

> [...] since the type of the data to be accessed isn’t known
>   in advance, directly using standard operators has some optimization
>   limits. For production code, we recommended that you take advantage of
>   the optimized pandas data access methods.

Comment: You cannot also create new columns with `.`; you can only access the existing columns.

Comment: great, that was exactly what i was looking for, so apart from creating new columns and the cases you listed above is there anything else [] can do?

Comment: At least not that I am aware of, or that the docs mention... Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am going thorugh this answer once again and Im wondering what type of data/column, would make [''] inferior to .iloc, .ix, .loc? Can you think of some basic example?

Comment: I don't think the indexing operators `[]` and `.` (these are called "standard operators" in the docs) are in any way inferior to `.iloc`, `.ix`, or `.loc` with respect to any data type in particular. Rather, as pointed out in the documentation, using "standard operators" might lead to sub-optimal code in terms of efficiency, because the Python interpreter is not aware in advance of the type of the data to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[]` will use the value of the index.

```
a = "hello"
df[a]        # It will give you content at hello
```

Using `.`

```
df.a         # content at a
```

The difference is that with the first one you can use a variable.